# Azure Powershell Script

Tags: azure, powershell

I have written a PowerShell script to print VM names with unmanaged disks however it's giving me an error. Appreciate any help on this -

```
$location=Read-Host -Prompt 'Input location for VMs'
$azuresubscription=Read-Host -Prompt 'Input Subscription Id'

$rmvms=Get-AzurermVM
# Add info about VM's from the Resource Manager to the array 
foreach ($vm in $rmvms) 
{     
    # Get status (does not seem to be a property of $vm, so need to call Get-AzurevmVM for each rmVM) 
    $vmstatus = Get-AzurermVM -Name $vm.Name -ResourceGroupName $vm.ResourceGroupName -Status  | where Location -like $location

    # Add values to the array: 
    $vmarray += New-Object PSObject -Property @{` 
        # Subscription=$Subscription.SubscriptionName; ` 
        Subscription=$azuresubscription.SubscriptionName; `
        AzureMode="Resource_Manager"; ` 
        Name=$vm.Name; PowerState=(get-culture).TextInfo.ToTitleCase(($vmstatus.statuses)[1].code.split("/")[1]); ` 
        Size=$vm.HardwareProfile.VirtualMachineSize} 
}

foreach ($vm in $vmarray)
{
    $vmdiskstatus = (Get-AzurermVM -Name $vm.Name -ResourceGroupName $vm.ResourceGroupName).StorageProfile.OsDisk.ManagedDisk
    if (!$vmdiskstatus) {Write-Host $vm.Name}
}
```

Error Message:

> ($vmarray is resulting in Null array) -
>
> Cannot index into a null array.
>
> Expected Output - $vmarray should have one VM as there is a running
>   instance in eastus (that's what I am using as value for $location)

Comment: You need to define your `$vmarray` BEFORE the `foreach ($vm in $rmvms)` loop in order to use it afterwards: `$vmarray = @()`

Comment: @theo, can you add your comment as answer? I read a lot of questions with responses on the comments and the questions remain "open".  It´s a suggestion... Thank you!

Comment: @VictorSilva You're right, a lot of questions are answered by comments. Sometimes it is hard to decide.. ('big' enough to be an answer or just a hint?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As requested by Victor Silva to add my comment as answer, here goes:

You need to define the `$vmarray` as array before entering the loop to add objects to it.
Then, after that loop, the `foreach ($vm in $vmarray)` *does* have an array to index into, even if empty:

```
$location=Read-Host -Prompt 'Input location for VMs'
$azuresubscription=Read-Host -Prompt 'Input Subscription Id'

$rmvms=Get-AzurermVM

###################################################
# create an array variable to collect the result(s)
###################################################
$vmarray = @()

# Add info about VM's from the Resource Manager to the array 
foreach ($vm in $rmvms) 
{     
    # rest of your code
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the quick response. I will give this a try and let you all know